# How to display Perl cgi results in on a HTML page instead of .cgi

Tags: forms, perl, iframe, cgi

Ok, I confess I'm a designer and know little about backend coding. I have a site with a frontend form created with HTML in WordPress. On submission the form action="/cgi-bin/test.cgi" method="POST"

Test.cgi receives form text and radio option inputs, calculates the values of the user-selected radio options, and displays the results in a table with plain text paragraphs above and below the table.

The browser loads //domain/test.cgi and the minimally formatted content is spread across the entire width of the browser.

Ideally, I would like to display the test.cgi result within a WordPress page so it is consistent with the rest of the site, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Goals:

1 - Create an HTML form with radio answer options for several questions, and have those sent to cgi script - Succes
2 - Create cgi script to calculate values of selected options and display results in a table explaing text content above and below the table (for the user to read), so the user can see them in their browser - Success
3 - Display the script results on a WP page in an iframe (or some other way) for a better visual experience - Fail

Is there a way to do this?

I tried a couple of things:

I thought I might be able to display the results in an iframe so I created a WP page with an iframe

```
<iframe src="/cgi-bin/test.cgi" width="300" height="450"></iframe>
```

I tried sending the form (when submitted by the user) to this iframe WP page after submission. I thought that when it loads it might run test.cgi. Didn't work. It may have run the script, but I don't think the form inputs were passed on to test.cgi because it came back with the error used when users don't fill in their email. But, it was in the iframe.

Then I tried to change the test.cgi script so it would send to the WP page in the browser. Basically this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
print "Location: /iframe-page-name\n\n";
script stuff here
#end of script
```

That resulted in server errors.

Comment: There are a couple of things at play here. Your idea of using an iframe is sound, but it cannot submit the data from the user. I don't fully understand your workflow yet, but in general what you probably want to do is add some Javascript to your page to do all of this, and use your Perl code as the backend. Make the page talk to it asynchronously, send responses back in a way that your frontend will understand and then integrate that into the existing page.